# R: pass entire dataframe as argument to custom function, or just needed columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, maintainability

I want to know what is better from usability/efficiency point of view: passing a dataframe to a function, alongside with the required column names, or just the data columns. Should there be a difference if the result vector must be added to the dataset or not? The latter would be returning a list, or a new dataframe.

It is something like this:

```
# entire dataframe
f_df <- function(df, col1, col2){
# note: col1 and col2 would be strings
df$sum <- df[,col1] + df[,col2]
df
}
data <- f_df(data, "a","b")

# just the variables
f_col <- function(col1, col2){
col1 + col2
}
data$sum <- f_col(data$a, data$b)
```

Comment: I'd personally think that a function should operate on the vectors and can then be added to whatever other object later. So, I'm voting for `f_col`, but I suspect there might be a good argument for the alternative. How's that for fence sitting? :-)

Comment: Passing vectors "feels right" to me, I guess you can always benchmark each scenario to test the efficiency. I'd also note that `dplyr` and pipes replace the need for many functions that operate on data frames, for example: `data %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(sum = sum(a, b)`.

Comment: A function that just requires the vectors of values is more flexible. You could mimic base R functions and support both `plot(dd$a, dd$b)` and `plot(b~a, data=dd)` by implementing a generic function. But really, this question is opinion based and not really a good fit for this site. It all depends on your specific application and what's right for you might not be right for others.

Comment: @MrFlick not sure how "what's more efficient" is an opinion-based question? Perhaps "there are times when one is more efficient than the other, here's when/why `X` is more efficient, here's when/why it's not".